# Is it possible to use Testacular for non-AngularJS app for end-to-end testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-runner, end-to-end

I'm building a simple app and want to use Testacular as the test runner. Testacular is simple to setup for unit testing but the possibility of using it for e2e also seems great, however my app will not be in AngularJS. Is this possible (or simple) to do or should I be looking more towards Selenium?

Comment: There is recent video which claims it's possible: http://youtu.be/5mHjJ4xf_K0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! From Testacular's [GH Page](http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular/):

> #### Testing Framework Agnostic
>
> Describe your tests with Jasmine, Mocha, QUnit. Or write a simple adapter for any framework 
>   you like.

Since the aforementioned testing frameworks aren't library-dependent, it would make sense that as long as you can test your library code using one of those frameworks you can use testacular to provide a test-runner for it.

**That being said** testacular is **not** selenium. It allows you to test your code in a browser environment but as far as I know doesn't provide navigation, DOM Querying, user-emulation etc. like selenium does. If you're looking for selenium functionality for your JS code you should check out [Soda](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) which is an awesome library written by TJ and the rest of the gods on Mt. Olympus ::cough:: I mean developers at LearnBoost that provides a JS adapter for selenium's wire protocol, among other things.

But if you still think testacular is the way to go then take a look at their [sample configuration file](https://github.com/testacular/testacular/blob/master/test/client/testacular.conf.js) which should get you started in the right direction. Hope this helps!